# From whom abstraction hides implementation?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, abstraction

I know the architecture, how we can implement abstraction using the interface and an abstract class.
But **from whom** we are hiding the implementation?

**As a developer**, anyone can click on that method and can see the classes which are giving implementations for those abstract methods.

**As a user**, he will be only facing UI, so he is not going to see the code anyway.

Then my question from whom we are hiding the implementation?

Comment: We aren't hiding it in a security sense, but to stop people writing code which depends on implementation details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface?r=SearchResults&s=1|204.3958

Comment: Sometimes as a developer, you will be working on a big project. There will be other developers involved as well, "hiding implementation" also make it harder for others to change the data by mistake.

Comment: @tgdavies Depending on the specifics, it can in fact be a security matter, even in Java.

Comment: Dividing the world into **developers** and **users** is misleading; all developers _are_ users of other developers' work. In a complex application, I'm often the developer of a piece that I then turn around and consume from another layer, several times in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

We are hiding it from clients of the interface, so that they don't depend on things which might change. A client of an interface is a piece of code which calls the interface.

Let's say I write a stack interface:

```
interface Stack {
  push(String s);
  String pop();
}
```

and an implementation:

```
class StackImpl {
  public List contents;
  public void push(String s) {
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

If clients use StackImpl, they might start accessing the `contents` directly, which will mean that I can't change the implementation to use an array without breaking all the clients.
If they only use `Stack`, we can improve the implementation without affecting the clients.